# SSRS - Table of Contents Printed in order to extract a TOC to Word printed

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, tableofcontents

I'm following this thread:
[Table of Contents for PDF/Printed Report in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748850/table-of-contents-for-pdf-printed-report-in-ssrs)

I already have this two SQL Statements:

- The table to store the report data (I create the table inside the Report database):

  ```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_TOC](
  [RID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [TOCExecutionID] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [AssessmentID] [int] NULL,
  [ReportName] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [GlobalsTotalPages] [int] NULL,
  [LoadDate] [datetime] NULL DEFAULT (getdate())
  ) ON [PRIMARY]
  ```
- And I create the Store Procedure:

  ```
  create proc rpt_dsTOC
  @TOCExecutionID varchar(50)
  as
  if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') is not null drop table #temp
  create table #temp (
      ord int NOT NULL,
      ReportName varchar(50) NULL,
      PageCnt int NULL,
      PageNo int null )

  ;with ctePageCount as (
  select distinct t.ReportName
      , t.GlobalsTotalPages PageCnt
      , t.TOCExecutionID
      , t.AssessmentID
  from        tbl_TOC t
  where        TOCExecutionID=@TOCExecutionID
  )
  insert into #temp
  select case when ReportName like 'Plan%' then 1  --List all of the          names of the subreports here
          when ReportName like 'Busin%' then 2
          when ReportName like 'Threa%' then 3
          when ReportName like '%Manag%' then 4
          when ReportName like '%Monit%' then 5
          when ReportName like 'Pande%' then 6
          when ReportName like 'Emerg%' then 7
          when ReportName like 'Key%' then 8
          when Reportname like 'Netw%' then 9
          else 10 end ord
      , ReportName
  , PageCnt
  , 0 PageNo
  from ctePageCount
  ```
- This section calculates the pagenumber by using the total number of pages in each section

  ```
  declare @run int = 3
  declare @ord int, @ReportName varchar(50), @PageCnt int, @PageNo int
  declare     c cursor for
      select    ord
      , ReportName
      , PageCnt
      , PageNo
  from #temp
  order by ord;
  open c
      fetch next from c into @ord, @ReportName, @PageCnt, @PageNo
      update #temp set PageNo=@run
      set @run = @run + @PageCnt--5
  while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 --EOF
  begin
      fetch next from c into @ord, @ReportName, @PageCnt, @PageNo
      if @PageNo=0
      set @PageNo = @run
      update #temp set PageNo=@PageNo where ord=@ord 
      set @run = @PageNo + @PageCnt
  end
  close c
  deallocate c

  select * from #temp order by ord
  ```

However HOW my table tbl_TOC will be loaded with the report details?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh - so sorry!  I neglected to include one step.  The dll calls a stored procedure.  usp_LogReportAttributes

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[usp_LogReportAttributes] 
      @TOCExecutionID       VARCHAR(50)
    , @AssessmentID         int
    , @ReportName           VARCHAR(50)
    , @GlobalsTotalPages    INT

as
begin

delete from tbl_TOC where LoadDate<dateadd(day,-1,getdate())--just periodic maintenance so this table doesn't get too big

insert into tbl_TOC (
      TOCExecutionID
    , AssessmentID
    , ReportName
    , GlobalsTotalPages
)
--values (@TOCExecutionID, @AssessmentID, @ReportName,@GlobalsTotalPages)
select   @TOCExecutionID
       , @AssessmentID
       , @ReportName
       , @GlobalsTotalPages
where not exists (select 1 from tbl_TOC t where t.TOCExecutionID = @TOCExecutionID and t.ReportName = @ReportName)
end
```